# Could someone explain the bug in my while loop

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out why the code keeps giving me an arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException over and over. Out of a desperate attempt I reversed the 2 Boolean conditions in my while loop and the program worked fine. The reason this really confuses me is because the two conditions are separated by an AND clause which should be commutative.

Here is the while statement that is in question:

```
while(compareIndex>=0 && key<data[compareIndex])//works
while(key<data[compareIndex] && compareIndex>=0) //Crashes
```

And for some context here is the rest of the method body:

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] data){
    for(int i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
        int key = data[i];
        int compareIndex = i-1;
        while(key<data[compareIndex] && compareIndex>=0){
            data[compareIndex+1] = data[compareIndex];
            compareIndex--;
        }
        data[compareIndex+1] = key;
    }

}
```

Comment: && does short-circuit evaluation. Let's say `compareIndex` is equals to -1. In your second condition, which statement will be evaluated first ? Is this valid ?

Comment: if `i` is `0`, `i-1` is `-1` and therefore `data[compareIndex]` accesses index `-1` (whichdoesn't exist and throwsan exception)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are saying. Could you further explain how && short-circuits evaluation?

Comment: @Maksim Conditions in `if` are computed sequentially and when the first condition is false, the remaining conditions are not examined at all (if there is AND operation)

Comment: @Maksim You can google that

Comment: it's simple: if(a && b) { do something } : Now, if you know a is false, whats the point of evaluating b?  You don't need to, you can short circuit the evaluation.  Notice this is not true for ||

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int compareIndex = i-1; // <-- on the first iteration i = 0, and i-1 = -1
while(key<data[compareIndex] && compareIndex>=0)
```

you cannot index an array with -1

**SIDE NOTE:**
You should develop your code in an IDE, and step through it in a debugger.  If you're not doing this, programming is going to be much harder.  Invest the time now to learn how to do this, and you'll be a much better programmer.  Try [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), they are free.  Do a google search on stepping through your code in a debugger.

Comment: your condition should be while(compareIndex>=0 && key<data[compareIndex])

Comment: @Bedouin, that would work, but I think I'm going to focus my answer on why his code crashes, and how he can identify this in future programming.

Comment: Anytime, glad to help

Answer (score 3):

It crashes because when you do:

```
while(key<data[compareIndex] && compareIndex>=0) //Crashes
```

the key value of compareIndex is `i-1` = `0-1` = `-1`

which is not a valid array position.
While when you try the other way around, compareIndex>=0 returns `false` hence the second part of the statement is not checked at all.

Answer (score 1):

When i == 0, right on the first loop, the value of compareIndex is -1. When you try to acess data[-1], you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

When you do

```
while(compareIndex>=0 && key<data[compareIndex])
```

as compareIndex >= 0 is false, the code never tries do evaluate key < data[compareIndex].

But when you do

```
while(key<data[compareIndex] && compareIndex>=0)
```

it tries to evalute key

Answer (score 1):

`compareIndex` is -1, so when you do this

```
data[compareIndex]
```

it crashes because `-1` is not a valid index.

---

The reason why the following doesn't crash is because of shortcutting

```
while(compareIndex>=0 && key<data[compareIndex])//works
```

it evaluates the clauses from left to right, so it evaluates `compareIndex>=0` first, and after it does that, your predicate looks like the following

```
while(false && something_else)
```

That is always guaranteed to be `false`, no matter what, so the compiler doesn't even bother with the `data[compareIndex]`, part, which is what is making it crash.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code `while(key<data[compareIndex] && compareIndex>=0)` crashes is because first the value at index `compareIndex` in the array `data` is computed but since the index is out of bounds for the array `data`.

On the other hand, when you use `while(compareIndex>=0 && key<data[compareIndex])`, first the result of `compareIndex>=0` is computed and if it is false (as it is in your case), the next condition is not examined.

Answer (score 0):

The array cannot be with negative index. In some cases like C++ GLUT, It does not mind the 'minus', so you can write array[0][-1] and it ignores negative number and takes it like array[0][1]. (I faced with it while i was programming in c++ with glut). So, java is sensitive, you need to check your index before you can make an operation. Also as I can see, this is bubble sorting. Maybe check Arrays.sort() function instead of this mess.